# What is the voltage value measured by an 8-bit ADC chip showing a binary reading of 64? the reference voltage is 3.3V

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, adc, converter

I followed the explanation in this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129325/what-is-the-significance-of-8-bits-in-the-context-of-an-adc0808).

I did 3.3 V/256 = ‭‭0.01289 V .

I also did 3.3 V/(256/1.5) = ‭0.01964 .

And lastly, I used this formula:

[image: formula:]

I just keep getting the wrong answer! Please could you explain it too because my professor gave us a general explanation about ADC without any formulas, and I have done my researches but still confused since I keep getting the wrong results!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it just \$3.3/256*64 = 0.825V\$ ?

Comment: Strange formula, usually on ADC datasheets we use "Resolution" to mean the number of bits (e.g. 8). Formula should actually use number of codes (2^8=256). Then by dimensional analysis you have 256 LSB / 3.3V = 64 LSB / 0.825V = 25% of full scale.

Comment: By the way, this is what I mean by LSB as a unit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/188922/35022

Comment: Which ADC actually is it? Just saying what the reference voltage is doesn't preclude that the actual ADC may have a differential input or use some fraction of the 3.3 volts as the real reference. What is the 1.5 all about - what made you choose 1.5 as a factor? What are the zero and gain errors associated with the actual ADC?

Comment: 64 is 25% of 256, so the voltage is 25% of 3.3 V, give or take the odd half step that some people insist on using as if it really meant anything in presence of noise and all the other odd little errors of the order of 1LSB.

Comment: The system voltage is not the reference voltage, so your formula is implicitely wrong.

Comment: A: Ref is 3.3V. B: ADC is 8 bits wide so you have 2^8=256 steps. C: Each step is 1/256 of 3.3V. D: Thus 64 steps is 64*3.3/256.

Comment: What that formula calls "system voltage" is what we in the business call VRef or Voltage Reference, also known as Full-Scale Output. Since 3.3V is a commonly used power supply voltage rail, we're assuming that this 8-bit ADC is using the 3.3V supply as its voltage reference. For higher resolution ADCs that's not good practice, because noise on the power supply will cause performance problems. But 8 bits is pretty low resolution, and the LSB size is less than typical power supply noise, so using supply as reference is a fair assumption in this case.

Comment: It is just a simple ratio:  \$\frac{64}{256} \cdot 3.3\ V = 0.825\ V\$